# XCM Transfer | How to get account addresses of rococo, mangata?

Tags: xcm, transfer

I rewrote some examples of transfer assets from `rococo` to some `parachains` like `mangata`, `rockmine`, `dali`.... on the blockcoder repository at https://github.com/blockcodes/xcm-sdk
I don't know how to get addresses like: `rockmine, rococo, mangata` account addresses to check for my purpose transfer?

```
const beneficiaryValue = "<rockmine account address>" ???? // account address
export const rococoExampleUtils = {
    rococoRpc: 'wss://rococo-rpc.polkadot.io',
    rockMineRpc: 'wss://rococo-rockmine-rpc.polkadot.io',
    rockMineParachainId: 1000,
    mangataParachainId: 2110,
    daliParachainId: 2087,
    senderMnemonic: '???', 
    rockmineDestinationAccount: '???',
    daliDestinationAccount: '???',
    rococoDestinationAccount: '???',
    mangataDestinationAccount: '???',
    rocAmount: 500000000000, // 0.5 ROC
  }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `destination account` is the account in the destination parachain you want to send the transfer to.

If you go to `examples/rococo` in that folder you can see where this values are used. Let's take Rockmine as a example ([rococo-to-rockmine.ts](https://github.com/blockcoders/xcm-sdk/blob/main/src/examples/rococo/rococo-to-rockmine.ts)):

```rs
await provider.limitedTeleportAssets({
    'Parachain',
    rockMineParachainId,
    'AccountId32',
    rockmineDestinationAccount,
    amount,
  })
```

The first parameter is the destination to transfer the asset. In this case we are transferring an asset from relaychain to a parachain so we set 'Parachain'.

The second parameter is the destination value which in this case is the Para_id of the parachain we are transfering the value: Rockmine.

The third one is the beneficiary traget, in this case an AccountId32 and the fourth is what you were asking for, is the beneficiary value, the account address to send the asset

You can see your accounts in Rockmine in the accounts tab in Polkadot JS: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-asset-hub-rpc.polkadot.io#/accounts

Comment: Thank you so much. Have a good day.